# How to add citation for the whole section of a report?

Tags: citations

I'm preparing a report for the company where I work and the whole section in a chapter of the report (the theoretical part) is from a text book. Of course I've summarized the book but the whole section is from that book.

How should I cite the book?

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand whether you paraphrased (restated in your own words) or reproduced (quoted verbatim) the book section.

If the former, just start the section in your report with something akin to: "The following section is based on Smith (2006, pp. 98-99)."

If the second, clearly mark the whole section as quotation (e.g. with quote marks and indentation), and append the correct reference:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent massa turpis, luctus eget sapien et, posuere sollicitudin massa.
>
> Morbi eu velit nunc. Aliquam consequat sagittis nibh, quis dictum nisi tempor." (Smith 2006, pp. 98-99)

That said, overly long citations or paraphrases usually indicate that you failed to distill what's relevant and apply it to your specific context. I'd consider rewriting your section with a clear idea in mind of what you want to convey and why.